# Cross domain auth token

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular application running on localhost:4200. When I sign in or register, I receive a token from the server that I store in the local storage and redirect the user to the dashboard. My use case is that once sign in button is hit, I need to redirect the application to a different domain let's say localhost:5300. Since local storage is domain specific, I can't access the token I stored on 4200 here at 5300. Is there any way that I can get around this ? Any hint will suffice!

Comment: You can use nginx to proxy them on the same domain

Comment: you can also attach your token to request header. Goal is to forward the token on your redirection and find it back on your other domain.